# How to install Oracle Java 8 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

Previously, there was an easy way to install Java 8 on Ubuntu using `webupd8team` repository. But currently it does not work and packages are not located.

Comment: are you sure you want oracle java? If you use it for commercial/business uses you need a business license. If you install the openjdk it's free. https://dzone.com/articles/installing-openjdk-11-on-ubuntu-1804-for-real

Comment: I need this one for Spark. https://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SPARK-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after spending a lot of effort on such a common case I decided to add this post.
I used several resources to achieve it.

1. Uninstall openjdk `sudo apt-get purge openjdk*`
2. Go to [this](https://rtmccormick.com/2018/04/29/how-to-manually-install-java-8-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/) blog post and run all steps until 4. If you have issues on step #3 go to step 3 in this post (sorry for numbering :))

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm-oracle

sudo cp ~/Downloads/(name of your tarball) /usr/lib/jvm-oracle 

cd /usr/lib/jvm-oracle

sudo tar -xvzf (name of tarball)

cd jdk1.8.0_(corresponding version)

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm-oracle/jdk1.8.0_{version}/bin/java 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm-oracle/jdk1.8.0_{version}/bin/javac 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/lib/jvm-oracle/jdk1.8.0_{version}/bin/javaws 1

sudo cat > /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm-oracle/jdk1.8.0_221"
export PATH="$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin"
Ctrl+d
```

3. (Optional) Make sure java alternatives are updated `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

### Update

You can download  Java from [here](https://oraclemirror.np.gy/jdk8/)

Comment: you should include the steps from the blog post here

Comment: OK, I will add them.

Comment: This is how I do it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Download the [JDK 8 SDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Create a directory at `/usr/lib called jvm-oracle`. You will need to use the sudo command as this directory is at root level:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm-oracle
```

Copy your tarball over:

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/(name of your tarball) /usr/lib/jvm-oracle
```

Move into the /usr/lib/jvm-oracle and extract your tarball:
Move into: cd /usr/lib/jvm-oracle
Extract: `sudo tar -xvzf (name of tarball)`

List out the directory contents and find your extracted folder: 
ls -al

You should see a directory like ‘jdk1.8.0_172’. Move into your dir and the bin folder with cd and list out the contents.
Move to new dir: `cd jdk1.8.0_172.`
Move to bin: cd bin
List out Contents: `ls -al`

Run these following commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm-oracle/jdk1.8.0_172/bin/java 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm-oracle/jdk1.8.0_172/bin/javac 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/lib/jvm-oracle/jdk1.8.0_172/bin/javaws 1
```

Then add the JAVA_HOME by these command:

```
echo $'\nJAVA_HOME='`which java` >> ~/.bashrc
```

Alternatively, you can add it manually by opening your .bashrc file and setting

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: it isn't different. I also used that same blog when I had to install it. 
But you wrote a small one, hence it was uploaded fast. But I wrote my answer in details hence I took a lot more time than you too. 
After that you edited your answer and then you downvoted mine just because both are same.

Comment: Pronoy's answer isn't different. He started replying more or less at the same time as you @gorros. No need to downvote his answer though.

Comment: yes, I undestand, I will remove down vote  ,but currently it is locked